# How to display a dynamic rating based on css and the value from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I want to display stars based on the value of PHP. 
The rating is between 0 to 5 and it is decimal (3.5, 3.75)

However, the stars that I can use are only full or half. So if it lower than 0.5 then I shall round it to zero, if it is more than 0.5 then round it to 1.

If it is 0.5, it stays 0.5.

The value from php is `$rating_sum` and it is calculated from the `sum_of_ratings` / `rating_times`

I use font awesome, so these are the stars `<i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-full">`

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: there are lots of readily available ratings scripts...let google be your friend

Comment: If you were to use a transparent png / gif image in conjunction with the `meter` html tag you could achive a very fine grained star / rating system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this you must setup $rating_sum first :

```
<?php

    $average_stars = round($rating_sum * 2) / 2;
    $drawn = 5;
    for ($i = 0; $i < floor($average_stars); $i++)
    {
        $drawn--;
        echo ' fullstar';
    }

    if ($rating_sum - floor($average_stars) == 0.5)
    {
        $drawn--;
        echo ' halfstar';
    }
?>
```

Comment: you deserve an award. thank you!